# Gustar en proposición adjetival. ¿Todavía requiere el subjuntivo?

Tags: subjuntivo

Entiendo que la oración

> No me gusta que estés parado.

requiere el subjuntivo del verbo *estar*. Pero si cambiamos la oración así,

> La cosa que no me gusta es que estés parado.

¿Todavía va a requerir el subjuntivo del verbo *estar*?

Comment: Yo **no** pensaría que se usaría el subjuntivo, pero será interesante lo que la gente dice. Lo digo porque en este caso es casi más **cierto** y quizás hay menos dudo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

¿Requiérese el subjuntivo?  **No.**

¿Admítese el subjuntivo?    **Sí**.

---

Doyte un ejemplo que creo que te lo hará claro.

- La cosa de las mujeres que me gusta es que me inviten a salir con ellas.
   <sup>*(hablo de las mujeres en general; soy viejísimo, feísimo y paupérrimo y hay una escasa posibilidad de que me hablen)*</sup>
- La cosa de las mujeres que me gusta es que me invitan a salir con ellas.
  <sup>*(son mujeres que conozco y me suelen invitar a tomar copas con ellas)*</sup>

---

Es decir, la diferencia está en si hablamos de una situación o cosa ya existente o algo más general que solo quizás exista/acaezca.  En tu ejemplo, si la persona con que hablas está parada actualmente usaremos el indicativo.  Si hablas generalmente de que no te gusta cuandoquiera que esté parada (es decir, general e hipotéticamente), esté esa persona parada o no en la actualidad, usaremos el subjuntivo.

Comment: +1 por "Doyte", parecía Asturiano pero esta bien escrito!

Comment: @AlexBcn N'asturianu sedría «Doite un exemplu que creyo que te lo fadrá claro» ;-)